# Javascript concatenate + and assign +=?

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation, assignment-operator

I'm reading a book on Javascript I've got to a confusing part regarding assignment operators and concatenation. Please see below code

```
var msg = 'JavaScript'; msg += ' Code'; //Concatenate
var intA = 8; intA -= 4; //Subtract and assign
var intB = 24; intB *= intA; //Multiply and assign

var str = 'Add & assign string: ' + msg;
    str += '<br>Multiply & assign: ' + initB;
```

I get that the `+=` operator, when dealing with strings concatenates the two operands and when dealing with numbers they add the values of the operands and reassign to the computed value to first operand.

I also get that `str` is being initialised as `'Add & assign string ' + msg;` and then appended with another string and a variable.

But why would you not just write the below in the example of the `str` variable?

```
var str = 'Add & assign string ' + msg + '<br>Multiply & assign: ' + initB;
```

Am I misunderstanding a subtle difference between + and += , or are they the same thing in this use case?

Comment: They are exactly the same.

Comment: `foo += bar` is just syntactic sugar for`foo = foo + bar`

Comment: No, you're not misunderstanding. Your code does produces exactly the same thing as the example code. I think they were just trying to illustrate different means of achieving the same result.

Comment: Jecoms ... Say you don't know if foo is undefined foo = foo + bar is an error. foo += bar is not. += assigns if foo is undefined.

Comment: @David That's not true. I just tested it and both throws error

Comment: Some time ago in a JavaScript course I remember the tutor saying that as strings are immutable objects, each _operation_ costs the browser to store a new value, and depending how many _operations_, the browser can waste time managing _garbage collection_. Due that I think your one-line alternative is preferable.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I thought as much, but being a newbie I wasn't too sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression like

```
a += b
```

is interpreted (almost) exactly as if it were written

```
a = a + b
```

Contrived examples explaining language constructs are contrived, and do not necessarily reflect common practice. (It'd be nice if they did, but creating code examples is notoriously difficult.)

Comment: I wrote "(almost) exactly" because I'm naturally cautious, but after some thought I can't come up with an example of when the interpretation would end up doing different things.